# send sql server Timestamp from C#

Tags: c#, timestamp

Does someone knows how can I send a Timestamp value from C# to my Sql stored procedure which expect to get a timestamp value?

the sp looks like this

create sp1(@TS Timestamp)

--do do something...

go

Answer (score 0):

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
command.CommandText =@"sp1";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.Add("@TS", MySqlType.TimeStamp, 15).Value = DateTime.Now;

Comment: instead of DateTime.Now, can I assign a hex value which is a timestamp I took from somewhere else?

Comment: Try to use this for conversion. 
http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/10/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-.net-datetime.aspx